# Windows 10: set multiple application windows to not combine in Task Bar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

On a `Windows 10 Pro 64-bit` PC with dual monitors, I have 3 instances of the FileZilla application open.

On the main monitor, 3 separate taskbar buttons appear. However, on the secondary monitor they combine into 1 taskbar button.

I have asked Windows to `Never combine` Taskbar buttons.

How do I resolve this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see if the taskbar on the second monitor has the same settings?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin The Taskbar Properties is the same window for all displays. He needs to change the Multiple Displays options as suggested in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I see that now. Appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the `Never combine` for Multiple Displays separately:

[image]